# Error Failed to create a worklet even though react-navigation plugin is there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am making a very simple drawer following all the steps in the react-navigation docs

I installed all the deps needed...

package.json file :-

```
{
  "name": "drawer-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

but I'm getting this error:  Error: Failed to create a worklet. Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js? See installation docs at https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation#babel-plugin., js engine: hermes

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f32IW.png)

The error happens even though I have the reanimated plugin in the babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

As you can see the plugin is the last plugin in the array so does anyone know how to solve this?